# ¿Por qué me aparecen cuadrados negros en la pantalla cuando navego por la página?

Tags: soporte

Desde hace un tiempo noté un algo extraño en la página: algunos momentos al ingresar se ven cuadrados negros en la pantalla, que parpadean y cambian de lugar cuando uno mueve el ratón o se desplaza por esta.

Esto no lo había visto antes en ninguna otra página. El problema se soluciona refrescando la página y se presenta muy rara vez, tampoco dificulta la interacción con la pagina pero es extraño que suceda.

Algunos detalles:

- El problema aparece cuando navego en Chrome (el navegador que uso
  comunmente), Versión 66.0.3359.139 (Build oficial) (32 bits) aunque no he probado en otros navegadores.
- El sistema operativo que manejo es windows 7 de 64 bits.
- Los cuadrados cambian de lugar cuando paso el ratón por encima de un enlace.

El problema se ve de la siguiente manera:

> [image]

¿A alguien le ha ocurrido esto también? ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por que pasa?

Comment: En mi caso nunca he observado ese comportamiento. Esos cuadrados aparecen al ponerte encima del enlace a la pregunta? o al ponerte encima de los tags?

Comment: Las figuras aparecen en cuanto ingreso a la pagina, solo cambian de lugar cuando muevo el ratón sobre una pregunta o enlace.

Comment: Tampoco he observado eso. El problema podría deberse a alguna extensión. Para confirmar/descartar esto intenta en modo de navegación incógnito con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas.

Comment: @the-breaker Tampoco me ha pasado eso sera algín pŕoblema con tu navegador

Comment: @Rubén, si ya lo intenté, se ve todo normal, notificare si vuelve a pasar.

Comment: A mi me pasa a veces en el chat que me salen unas lineas negras, uso Firefox en Win7

Comment: @blonfu, puede ser por lo mismo, busca una opción de _aceleración de hardware_ en tu navegador y desactivala

Comment: Si tienes el SO de 64 bits. ¿no sería mejor que usaras Chrome en 64bits también?

Comment: @Rubén, si, después de años con el mismo navegador recién me fije, lo tomare en cuenta

Answer (score 3):

Googleando [black squares google chrome] resulta que hay muchos reportes similares en diferentes sitios sobre problemas similares con diferentes páginas web.

Pensaba que lo más probable era que se tratara de un problema causado por una extensión de Chrome más que un bug de Stack Overflow en español o de los sitios de Stack Exchange en particular porque varios usuarios (tres al momento) hemos votado positivo el [comentario de Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3476/posible-bug-en-la-pantalla-de-la-p%C3%A1gina#comment12378_3476) en el que menciona que no se ha observado ese comportamiento pudiéndose asumir que ese voto lleva implícito "Yo tampoco".

Como comentó the-breaker hay algunos hilos que mencionan que la solución es desactivar la aceleración de hardware del navegador.

No he encontrado ningún hilo en Meta Stackoverflow reportando un problema similar reciente, pero está [Huge loading indicator after changing team image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315689/1595451)
 que era un bug the SO for Teams el cual fue corregido.

Comment: pues no, parece que no es un problema de la pagina, también puse [black squares google chrome] en google y en la primera opción [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jUbPJZ4CFu0) hablan del problema y dan la solución; desactivar la opción _Utilizar aceleración por hardware cuando este disponible_ en la sección de _Configuración_ de Chrome.